# Changing label color when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, colors, clicking

I am completely puzzled. I have been trying to figure this thing out forever. I am the trying to change the color of the label when the user clicks the checkbox. The code below works fine in the fiddle but won't work on the website. I call the google api right before the . Is there anything else that could be causing that? Something I should lookout for?

HTML

```
<div class="product_checkbox_div">
<input type="checkbox" name="1" id="check1" value=""/>
<label class="product_ingredients_list">Yes</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.product_checkbox_div{padding-top:0.5%;padding-bottom:0.5%;vertical-align:top;}
.product_ingredients_list{font-family:Calibri;font-size: 1em;color: #101010;font-weight:     normal;vertical-align:top;}
.product_ingredients_list_1{font-family:Calibri;font-size: 1.15em;color: #f33;font-weight: normal;vertical-align:top;}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$( '.product_checkbox_div' ).on( 'click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
$( this ).next('label').toggleClass( 'product_ingredients_list_1', this.checked );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdN7D/99/)

Thanks

Comment: Any error on the console =S?

Comment: Do you have a link to the website?

Comment: It's still on localhost. But I have another page with checkboxes that work fine. I don't change the color on it, just make a div appear but it works fine. So I am confused on why that javascript code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here you go.......**

http://jsfiddle.net/aqRrz/

```
$("document").ready(function () {

    $("input#check1").click(function () {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $(this).next('label').addClass('product_ingredients_list_1');

        } else {

            $(this).next('label').removeClass('product_ingredients_list_1');

        }

    })

});
```

Comment: OMGG! This worked! I am going to choose it at the right answer. But one more question about something that makes me even more puzzled... I actually managed to make the other code after playing around with it by simply adding "async" next to the script. However, when I leave async, your code doesn't work! I have to remove the async next to <script> for it to work. That makes no sense!!! Do you know why that would be? I thought async just helped with asynchronous loading...

Comment: Async shouldnt have any effect on the code I posted. I dont know why thats causing it to not work

Comment: Well, something is definitely extremely weird with my code. I tried adding/removing "async" a couple of times in a row and it totally affects it... Thanks for the help!